# Zoo Visitor Edit Profile: if field == problem

Tags: members, zoo-visitor

How do I check a member field for an answer, and if the answer is there display a new filed.

I am building a 2 page sign up with Zoo Visitor and the second page asks a question based on your answer in the first page.

```
{if custom_field_name == "ANSWER" }
<div class="category_select">
<category_menu>
<label for="categories">Ask Question?</label>
<select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4" multiple="multiple">
<select_options>
</select>
</category_menu>
</div>{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

```
{if "{custom_field_name}" == "ANSWER" }
```